# Remap function keys to commands?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, shortcut-keys, brightness

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Samsung Series 9 (900X3A-A03), and changing the brightness through the function keys or the brightness control UI causes flickering and general instability, so I have a script that changes brightness through ACPI and works perfectly. What would be the simplest way to remap my brightness keys (Fn+F2, Fn+F3) to the new command?

I've tried using the Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts interface in the system settings, but the current XF86MonBrightnessUp function still seems to take precedence.

Edit: Ended up solving this one by updating to the Quetzal 3.5 kernel and the latest X from Ubuntu-X-Swat.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Lester [solved the problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/172148/44179) in his question:

> Edit: Ended up solving this one by updating to the Quetzal 3.5 kernel and the latest X from Ubuntu-X-Swat.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all; it solves the OP's original problem in a different, but his question was how to remap the function keys, not how to get rid of the flickering :/